# Motorolla TeamBadge Issue

Tags: networking, wifi, multicast

I have A setup of Motorolla EBW100 Team Badges (typical Walkie Talkie). My wifi is configured as Such that it has Multiple SSIDs For different Badges. Like in Floor **A** I want 10 Team Badges to work with SSID **ABC** and for floor **B** another 10 with SSID **DEF**.

In theory it is a pretty simple setup. I am able to Communicate between the Team Badges. But i am also able to transmit from ABC to DEF (which I don't want). So if a user in Floor A wants to talk to his mate on same floor, they both use SSID ABC. When they Push to Talk, their conversation is also heard in DEF. Vice Versa is also True.

I Have HP Procurve switch that is connected to my Motorolla AP 7131.

I have a HP Default VLAN (Native).

Motorolla Says that we need to Disable multicasting at Switch Level.

I am not too sure.

Comment: What are you not sure about?  Whether the solution from Motorolla is correct or how to make the suggested change in your switch?

Answer (score 1):

That motorolla Solution is Correct. I have another setup where it works on a single WIFI Vlan... I Cant disable multicasting (obvious Reasons of Routing ) , I think motorola wants to give me a band aid fix..I aint buying that.